# Picking Colors of Shirts

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

If I have a set of 12 shirts comprised of 4 blue, 4 yellow, and 4 red shirts, how many shirts do I have to pick to ensure that there are at least 3 of one color?

Comment: Yes, I understand that it's 7 (sorry, my question wasn't clear). How can this be written using the Pigeonhole Principle's formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the worst case scenario to *not* have at least three of a color?

> When you have somehow picked two red, two blue, and two green shirts

If you pick one more shirt, are you guaranteed three of a color?

More generally, completely ignoring the number of each shirt available (*as it is unnecessary information that plays absolutely no role in the solution to the question*) the pigeonhole principle says that if you have $n$ objects divided into $k$ categories, you will necessarily have some category with at least $\lceil\frac{n}{k}\rceil$ objects in it.

Here, $k=3$ is the number of categories (the colors of shirts).

What is the smallest $n$ that works (number of shirts to select) so that $\lceil\frac{n}{3}\rceil \geq 3$?

Comment: With $\lfloor \frac{n}{3} \rfloor $, $n = 9$. But in the worst-case, two shirts of each color + one shirt of any would be 7 shirts. Wouldn't it be the ceiling function, as $ \lceil \frac{n}{3} \rceil \geq 3 $ for $n = 7$?

Comment: @apizzimenti, @ SubhadeepDey, you are correct.  I used the wrong symbol while not thinking.  It will indeed be the ceiling.  It could also be phrased as floor functions as $\lfloor\frac{(n-1)}{k}\rfloor +1$ as I recall.